# How to change path in jboss portal

Tags: jboss-portal

How to change the path of the jboss portal url. eg Change url from "http://localhost:8082/portal/portal/myportal/cms" to "http://localhost:8082/portal/myportal/cms". How do i remove that extra "portal" from the url. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution. It might be useful for beginners like me.

Open the file jboss-web.xml located at "**E:\somefolder\jboss-portal-2.7.2\server\default\deploy\jboss-portal.sar\portal-server.war\WEB-INF\jboss-web.xml**" and change the `<context-root>/portal</context-root>` to `<context-root>/</context-root>`.

For more information go to [jboss site](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/GTNPORTAL34/Portal+URLs)